# Unit testing Angular Controller that uses Kendo Grid/Datasource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

My project is using AngularJS + Kendo-UI. I'm trying to test one of my Controllers that uses a Kendo-UI Grid:

```
angular.module('myApp')('DevicesCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/devices",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            },
            change: function(){
                var view = this.view();
                $scope.devices = [];

                $.each(view, function(i, v) {
                    $scope.devices.push({id: v.id, description: v.name, status: v.status  == 0 ? "failure" : "success"});
                });
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        },
        columns: [
            {
                field: "name",
                title: "Name",
                width: 250,
                template: function (item) {
                    var itemStatus = item.status == 0 ? 'failure' : 'success';
                    return '<div label size="small" operation="' + itemStatus + '" label="' + item.name + '"></div>';
                }
            },
            {
                field: "status",
                title: "Status"
            }
        ]
    };
});
```

When I wrote my unit test, I expected that a GET request would be called:

```
describe('deviceCtrl', function () {

    var scope, deviceCtrl, httpBackend, timeout;

    beforeEach(module("myApp"));
    beforeEach(module('src/modules/devices/views/device.html'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $httpBackend, $timeout, $state) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        timeout = $timeout;

        httpBackend.expectGET('languages/en_US.json').respond({});

        deviceCtrl = $controller("DeviceCtrl", {
            $scope: scope
        });

        $state.go("devices");
        timeout.flush()

    }));

    it('should load the switch list', function () {

        httpBackend.expectGET("/devices").respond(
            [{"id":"1","name":"name 1","status":"1"},
            {"id":"2","name":"name 2","status":"2"}]
        );

        httpBackend.flush();

    });

});
```

But the expectation is never satisfied, no requests are made.
So my question is: Is there a way to make Kendo Grid/Datasource to make this call, so I would be able to mock it?

I saw some samples on how to do it using Mockjax (http://www.telerik.com/forums/best-practice-mocking-with-datasource) but I would prefer to use angular libraries to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a lot of research I could find some ways to test Controllers that use Kendo Datasource.

Kendo has its own way to make the Ajax calls to fetch data and don’t use regular Angular $http to do that, so it’s a little bit tricky to test using Angular tools (angular-mocks).
Let’s go to the options:

**1 – Use regular Angular way to do the Ajax calls.**

Kendo lets us change the way it fetches data, so instead of doing:

```
dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/devices,
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            },
            change: function(){
                var view = this.view();
                $scope.devices = [];

                $.each(view, function(i, v) {
                    $scope.devices.push({id: v.id, description: v.name, status: v.status  == 0 ? "failure" : "success"});
                });
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        });
```

We would change to:

```
dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: function(options){
                    $http.get("/devices").then(function(response){
                        options.success(response.data);
                        $scope.devices = [];
                        response.data.forEach(function(v){
                            $scope.devices.push({id: v.id, description: v.name, status: v.status  == 0 ? "failure" : "success"});
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Then we can use regular $httpBackend.expectGET(url) to mock the Ajax call.
I personally like this approach because we have more control.
Ps.: using the variable “options” inside the function we have access to the Grid filter, sorting and paging values.

**2 – Mock the Kendo Ajax Call.**

In this way we change almost nothing at the Controller, the only changed needed is to create a new Datasource using new kendo.data.DataSource({}) instead of just passing the options.
This needed that because we call the read function inside the test case.
I tried different ways to mock this Ajax request, but the only one I could make it work was using a tool called [Jasmine-Ajax](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-ajax).
And in the test case we would wrote something like:

```
var request = jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent();
request.response(MockData);
```

I hope this can help other people.